# Unable to convert values from lowercase to uppercase using toupper

Tags: c, arrays, toupper

i'm attempting to create a program that asks the user to firstly enter the amount of values they would like to convert from lowercase to uppercase. The for loop then assigns each value into an array. The array then goes through another for loop to convert the values into uppercase using LowerToUpper function.

When i go to run the program, it will take in values and then start doubling them on the command window, and will cease when you have completed entering the values, rather than printf the results. Could you please explain why. Thank you in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void LowerToUpper(char* array)
{

        toupper(*array);
}

int main(void)
{
        int i, amount;
        printf("How many values?\n");
        scanf("%d", &amount);
        char *d;
        char array1 [amount];

        printf("Please enter the values\n");

        for(i=0; i<amount; i++)
        {
                scanf("%c", &array1[i]);
        }


        for(i=0; i<amount; i++)
        {
                d=&array1[i];
                LowerToUpper(d);
                scanf("%c", &array1[i]);
                printf("%c", array1[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Toupper` and `toupper` are not the same things, just sayin'.

Comment: `toupper` doens't change something to upper-case; it *returns* an upper-case conversion if available. The actual input argument is unchanged.

Comment: @WhozCraig beat you by 4 seconds. :)

Comment: What use is your `LowerToUpper` function? Besides the problem mentioned about your use of `toupper` it's doesn't really do anything usefull. Why not call `toupper` directly?

Comment: I also don't understand why you read input into `array1` *twice*? Especially since the second reading would (after you fix your `toupper` problem) will *overwrite* the character you just made upper-case.

Comment: Lastly, you really need to read and experiment more with [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and the `"%c"` format specifier, because the input you read will most likely *not* be the input you expect..

Comment: 1) `toupper(*array);` --> `*array = toupper(*array);` 2) `scanf("%c", &array1[i]);` ----> `scanf(" %c", &array1[i]);` 3) delete 2nd `scanf("%c", &array1[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `toupper()` properly. The function *returns* the converted value in case of success. You need to make use of the returned value. The supplied argument is not changed.

That said, the program structure is unnecessarily complicated. you can simplify it like

```
    for(i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
            int result = toupper (array1[i]);
            if (result != array1[i]) printf("%c", result); //just checkin', if converted
    }
```

---

That said, you have many other issue which you don't see at this moment, like

```
    scanf("%c", &array1[i]);
```

this will, to your surprise, only ask you for half the number of inputs. Why? You forgot to ignore the newline entered by <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key.

Then, you did not check for the success of `scanf("%d", &amount);` call. In case, the scanning fails, you'll end up with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The second `scanf()` inside the last `for` loop is probably something you don;t want, it's useless, at best.

Comment: It does keep only taking half the amount! really annoying. What do you mean by 'forgot to ignore the newline entered by the RETURN key'?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
toupper(*array);
```

to this:

```
*array = toupper(*array);
```

since [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) ref's mentions:

> **Return Value**
>
> The uppercase equivalent to c (`*array` in your case), if such value exists, or c (unchanged) otherwise. The value is returned as an int value that
>   can be implicitly casted to char.

---

PS: Defining a function `LowerToUpper()` for this operation (one line of code) is an overkill, and you could call that one line of code inside `main()` instead (I mean the body of the function to be moved into `main()`).

Comment: and some error check? BTW, a function is kinda overkill here, don;t you think?

Comment: Grr @SouravGhosh, you got there first..NIce answer, +1. Yes I do, but it might be basic educative stuff...

Comment: thanks for your replies! but it is for a question that requires me to use a function that takes a char pointer and returns nothing, whilst converting the values of a string.

Comment: @L.Kay then you should change your question. :)

Comment: @L.Kay too bad, because  the actual task of converting `n` chars to upper case and dumping them to `stdout` is considerably more trivial than they (whoever "they" are) is making it out to be. [something like this](https://ideone.com/dCRWWV).